# How to change a class into function while still maintaining Stack Navigation screen use?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Hello this is my first time asking a question on here/asking for help. I feel like I'm overlooking a simple solution. But my goal is to create a use switch navigator so when the application first begins it will open the terms and conditions but once agreed to, it will give a different set of screens. Right now I am having trouble using `React.useSet` in `TermsAndCondition.js` but I keep getting `Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:`
Now I understand that my class in `TermsAndConditions.js` needs to be a function but how do turn the class into a function while still being able to call it in `App.js` as a screen in Stack.Navigator.

I have also tried to just somehow import

```
state = {
    accepted: false,
  };
```

from the `TermsAndCondition.js` and use that as my conditional in `App.js` for switchNavigator but kept getting undefined or just simple errors. (I do apologize but I didn't save the errors for these attempts.) But most tutorials use the `React.useSet` and I haven't been able to find similar solutions.

`App.js`

```
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

import mapScreen1 from "./src/screens/mapScreen1";
import mapListScreen from "./src/screens/mapListScreen";
import Home from "./src/screens/Home";
import TermsAndConditions from "./src/screens/termscond";
import isAccepted from "./src/screens/termscond";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        {isAccepted ? (
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Terms and Conditions"
              component={TermsAndConditions}
            />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        ) : (
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
            <Stack.Screen name="mapListScreen" component={mapListScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="mapScreen1" component={mapScreen1} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        )}
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

`TermsAndCondition.js`

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

const isCloseToBottom = ({ layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize }) => {
  const paddingToBottom = 20;
  return (
    layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >=
    contentSize.height - paddingToBottom
  );
};

export const [isAccepted, setIsAccepted] = React.useState(true);

export default class TermsAndConditions extends Component {
  state = {
    accepted: false,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Terms and conditions</Text>
        <ScrollView
          style={styles.tcContainer}
          onScroll={({ nativeEvent }) => {
            if (isCloseToBottom(nativeEvent)) {
              this.setState({
                accepted: true,
              });
            }
          }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.tcP}>
            Welcome to our website. Terms And Condition.
          </Text>
        </ScrollView>

        <TouchableOpacity
          disabled={!this.state.accepted}
          onPress={() => setIsAccepted(!isAccepted)}
          style={this.state.accepted ? styles.button : styles.buttonDisabled}
        >
          <Text style={styles.buttonLabel}>Accept</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the following link will help you with transformation - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/five-ways-to-convert-react-class-components-to-functional-components-with-react-hooks

Comment: You can look here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#switch-navigator